# How to add a plus(+) sign in the user input

Tags: python

For example if I have code:

```
print("Give me keywords")
keywords = input()

print("Those are nice " + keywords)
```

lets say I input:

```
"Banana cocktail"
```

Now the question is: Is it possible for me to get it print:

```
"Those are nice Banana + cocktail".
```

So the idea is to get + sign every time the user puts space in their input.

Comment: splith them and insert `+` between them ?

Comment: What about `" + ".join(keywords.split())`?

Answer (score 0):

Either `split` and `join` as suggested in the comments, or `replace`:

```
print("Give me keywords")
keywords = input()

print("Those are nice " + keywords.replace(' ', ' + '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print("Those are nice ", ' + '.join(keywords.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options:

```
keywords.replace(' ', ' + ')
' + '.join(keywords.split())
re.sub('\s+', ' + ', keywords)
```

You should choose the method depending on that how many spaces do you have between words,
want you replace only spaces or some other things etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can split keywords and join the resultant list with '+'

```
' + '.join(keywords.split(' '))
```